# Воспроизведение видео из потока байт

Tags: android, videoview

У меня есть два приложения.
1-ое получает видео с веб-камеры и передает его по сокету в виде массива байт.
2-ое приложение принимает этот массив байт и это происходит бесконечно (т.е. мы передаем видео с камеры в реалтайме).
2-ое приложение - это андроид приложение и принимаемое видео мне нужно показать на экране. 
Для вывода на экран используется VideoView, но он принимает на вход или конечный файл, или ссылку на видео в сети.
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом можно вывести получаемый поток байт в VideoView?
Спасибо!